# Click handler for shapes in easeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs

I'm an EaselJS newbie. I'm following an outdated tutorial. I want to put numbered squares on a stage and then have them dissapear when I click on them.

The original code had an onPress event which I have modified to a click listener. However I get an error message about the scope of the "this" object within my click handler.

```
TypeError: this.stage is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
c99.Game = (function() {
    function Count99Game(){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');

        this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
        var totalTiles = 10;

        for(var i = totalTiles; i>0; i--){
            var tile = new c99.Tile(i);
            this.stage.addChild(tile);

            tile.x = Math.random()*(this.canvas.width - tile.width);
            tile.y = Math.random()*(this.canvas.height - tile.height);

            tile.addEventListener("click", function(event){
                this.stage.removeChild(event.target);
                this.stage.update();
            }).bind(this);
        }       

        this.stage.update();
    }

    return Count99Game;
})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside of EaselJS's `click` handler, `this` is the `window` object. You need to move your `bind` call to the listener function itself:

```
tile.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            this.stage.removeChild(event.target);
            this.stage.update();
        }.bind(this));
```

You can also set the handler's `this` manually using [`Shape.on`](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_on):

```
// pass outer `this` to event listener
tile.on("click", function(event){
            this.stage.removeChild(event.target);
            this.stage.update();
        }, this);
```

Comment: As I'm not familiar with this framework, I would prefer to use shorter version, supplied in this answer (if it will work). +1